# Can't get selected text in EditText using Google Gboard

Tags: java, android, text, edit

My application gets the selected text in an EditText using editText.getSelectionStart(); and editText.getSelectionEnd();

This works for "manual" selections, but not for selections created with the Gboard edit panel.

I am getting an empty string.

Is there a way to get the selected Gboard text without using a clipboard?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
int kStart = editText.getSelectionStart(), 
    kEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
if (kEnd > 0 && kEnd > kStart) {
    for (int i = kStart; i < kEnd; i++)
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
}
String sout = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.